# Docusign - developer account query

Tags: docusignapi

We have a developer account and I am starting to integrate it into our system. The system is based on Laravel/VueJS and I've 2 additions Eric Tucker Docusign SDK and the official Docusign SDK.

I've managed to create a template in our developer area, with custom fields (a question later regarding them) but wonder what happens when I have completed the system on our website. What happens going live? I presume that any template created in our account is used by associated users on our system - or do they have to create templates on their account and create custom fields etc?

Answer (score 0):

When you go live you'll have to move your templates/custom fields to the new production account (or the existing one).

More information about going live - https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/